# Include both INSERT and UPDATE queries in one SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert-update

I need to clear the revenue values from the Stage table from all records and then update the same from the working table. I am trying to do an `INSERT` and `UPDATE` in one stored procedure in SQL Server 2008. When I execute the `UPDATE` query and the `INSERT` query separately, they are working fine. However, when I try to include them in one stored procedure, I am getting a syntax error.

My stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF object_ID(N'[dbo].[usp_AtRiskAsset_SFLoadStaging]') IS NOT NULL
      DROP PROCEDURE [dbo ].[usp_AtRiskAsset_SFLoadStaging]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AtRiskAsset_SFLoadStaging]
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.ARA_Stage (Id, [CanceledRevenue], [YearToDateRevenue], [PriorYearRevenue])
        SELECT
            ARA.[Id],
            'NULL',
            'NULL',
            'NULL'
        FROM 
            dbo.ARA ARA
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.Asset AST ON AST.[Id] = ARA.Asset__c
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.[Case] CS ON CS.[Id] = ARA.Case__c
        WHERE 
            CS.IsClosed = 'false' 
            AND CS.Record_Type_Name__c = 'At Risk'
            AND AST.IsActive__c = 'true'

    UPDATE dbo.ARA_Stage
        SELECT 
            ARS.Id,
            ARW.CanceledRevenue,
            ARW.YearToDateRevenue,  
            ARW.PriorYearRevenue
        FROM 
            dbo.ARA_Working ARW
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.Account AC ON ARW.AccountNumber =  AC.Contract_Number__c
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.Asset AST ON ARW.PDCT01_ID = AST.PDCT01_Id__c
                          AND AST.AccountId = AC.Id
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.ARA ARS ON AST.Id = ARS.Asset__C
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.Product2 PRD ON ARW.PDCT01_ID = PRD.PDCT01_Id__c
                             AND AST.PDCT01_Id__c = ARW.PDCT01_ID
        INNER JOIN 
            [dbo].[Case] CS ON ARS.Case__c = CS.Id
        WHERE  
            CS.Account_Contract_Number__c = ARW.AccountNumber
            AND CS.Record_Type_Name__c = 'At Risk'
            AND CS.IsClosed = 'false'
END
GO
```

The error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_AtRiskAsset_SFLoadStaging, Line 46
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: `UPDATE ... SET ... FROM ...` not `UPDATE ... SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

You need map the columns from the select within the update 
by `set` keyword

For example

```
UPDATE dbo.ARA_Stage
SET [CanceledRevenue] = ARW.CanceledRevenue
...
```